# Is it possible using FFMPEG to replace one ".ts" file in a HLS ts file collection with another ".ts" file?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, streaming

There is a video, actually an HLS stream (sequence of TS files)
I would like to take out one TS chunk and replace it with another.
Another chunk will be encoded using same FFMPEG encoding settings.

In case you wonder why i need this:
There is a five hours HLS stream. One of TS has a wrong title on the video. I need to change that TS without re-encoding the whole HLS stream.

Currently i tried:

1. Take TS and convet it using FFMPEG into mp4
2. Edit mp4 video (change  title) and  save as new mp4
3. Convert new mp4 into new TS (using FFMPEG, same settings as was used for original video)
4. Replace original TS with the new TS.

But it doesn't work, player shows loading in progress icon. (in the network console i see that this new TS is loaded normally, with status 200)

As soon as i replace new TS with original one, player plays it normally.

Both TS files start with I-frame, both have audio. There's only a slight difference in the sequence of P and B frames.

```
old new
I   I
P   P
B   B
B   B
P   P
B   B
B   B
B   B
P   P
B   B
B   P
B   B
P   B
P   B
B   P
```

How can i get new TS chunk working in original TS sequence?

Update:

As per szatmary advice (below) i tried to include "-copyts" flag during all ts>mp4>ts conversions. Also tried "-copytb" flag with all 3 options -1, 0, and 1. However result still the same - player doesn't play HLS TS sequence (m3u8) with new TS chunk.

Adding "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY" tag after replaced TS in the M3U8 list, doesn't fix the situation.

Without "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY" tag, player gives error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) There appears to be a playback issue.

code: 4
message: "There appears to be a playback issue."

__proto__:
MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM: 0
MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: 5
MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
code: 0
message: ""
status: null
```

With "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY" tag, player gives error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) There appears to be a playback issue.

code: 3
message: "error"

__proto__:
MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM: 0
MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: 5
MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
code: 0
message: ""
status: null
```

Both TS files (old one and new one) have video and audio streams.

Looks like something else should be done. I think solution will be similar to ad insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to match timestamps. When converting to mp4 you will lose the time stamp data. You have to keep it as ts and use -copy ts. Even then , you will probably also lose continuity counters and need to place discontinuity tags in the m3u8. What you are trying to do is not really supported, and very difficult to get rite. I do something similar at my job, but we had to write custom software to make the transitions seamless.

Comment: Thank you szatmary. I tryed -copyts, -copytb -1, -copytb 0, -copytb 1, however it still doesn't play. Is there any specifics on placing discontinuity tags in the m3u8? Once again, thank you for your fast reply. Have a great weekend.

Comment: szatmary, at your job, using your custom software, have you managed to make new TS work between the old ones?

Comment: -copyts only works if the file you are encoding from has the same timestamp.  In your case it sounds like it does not.